# Mock New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig return value of type Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordBase[]

Tags: powershell, azure, pester

I'm trying to write a unit test for a script that uses `New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet`. The `DnsRecords` parameter on `New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet` validates that I pass in a type of `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordBase[]` which is the return value of `New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig`. The thing is, I can't seems to get anything to cast to that DnsRecordBase type.

Here is a dummy script that shows my issue:

```
function test-mocking {
  $arecordtype = New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -Ipv4Address 1.2.3.4
  New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "UT" -RecordType A -ResourceGroupName 'RG-UT' -TTL 60 -ZoneName 'zone1' -DnsRecords $arecordtype -Confirm:$False -Overwrite
}

Describe 'test-mocking' {
  Mock New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet { return 'sup' }
  Mock New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig { return '1.2.3.4' }

  it 'does nothing' {
    test-mocking
    Assert-MockCalled New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Describing test-mocking
 [-] does nothing 47ms
   PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "1.2.3.4" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordBase[]".
   ArgumentTransformationMetadataException: Cannot convert the "1.2.3.4" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordBase[]".
   ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'DnsRecords'. Cannot convert the "1.2.3.4" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordBase[]".
   at test-mocking, C:\Temp\testMock.ps1: line 3
   at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Temp\testMock.ps1: line 11
```

I've tried everything in place of "1.2.3.4"... Integer, String, Hashtable, Array, System.Object, `$null`

I also can't just run `New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig` to get the real object because that commandlet requires me to run Login-AzureRmAccount. This is part of a much larger script, I'm really just trying to mock these out to test other things inside the script.

I tried using Pester's new CMDLET `New-MockObject` but I get this error:

```
[-] does nothing 110ms
    MemberAccessException: Cannot create an abstract class.
    MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetUninitializedObject" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot create an abstract class."
    at New-MockObject, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\4.0.6\Functions\New-MockObject.ps1: line 22
    at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
    at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\4.0.6\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 1111
    at ExecuteBlock, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\4.0.6\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 1123
    at Invoke-Mock, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\4.0.6\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 966
    at <ScriptBlock><Process>, <No file>: line 119
    at test-mocking, C:\Temp\testMock.ps1: line 2
    at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Temp\testMock.ps1: line 11
```

Code:

```
function test-mocking {
  $arecordtype = New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -Ipv4Address 1.2.3.4
  New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "UT" -RecordType A -ResourceGroupName 'RG-UT' -TTL 60 -ZoneName 'zone1' -DnsRecords $arecordtype -Confirm:$False -Overwrite
}

Describe 'test-mocking' {
  Mock New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet { return 'sup' }  
  Mock New-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig { return New-MockObject -Type Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordBase }

  it 'does nothing' {
    test-mocking
    Assert-MockCalled New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to mock this object is:

```
New-MockObject -Type ([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordSet])
```

I had the same issue and found the full type in the 
[Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.dns/set-azurermdnsrecordset?view=azurermps-4.4.1#required-parameters) by looking at the type listed for the -RecordSet parameter.

**Update:** There is an easier way to get the full type if you can get an instance of the object type using `$object.GetType().FullName` Ex:

```
$temp = Get-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -ZoneName "myzone.com" -ResourceGroupName "myResources" -Name "mysite" -RecordType A
$temp.GetType().FullName
```

This will output `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Dns.DnsRecordSet`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `New-MockObject` to mock the object type you need: https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/New-MockObject

> New-MockObject is a Pester function (introduced in Pester 3.4.4) that
>   allows you to create "fake" objects of almost any type to run in
>   Pester mocks. These "fake objects" allow your mocks to return the same
>   type as the function it was mocking to pass the result to entities
>   that are strongly typed.

Comment: That's a really cool command, one that was new to me but unfortunately it doesn't work (or at least doesn't seem to work) for this command. I updated the post with the error. Thanks for answer!

Comment: It might be worth raising it as an issue on the pester project in GitHub, they are pretty responsive.

Comment: Similar issue, but looks like they worked around it: https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/806